# What does this error mean? With `useBuiltIns` option, required direct setting of `corejs` option

Tags: npm, babeljs

I just started getting this error in my static assets build with parcel.js. It works locally but my build on Heroku is erroring and I'm not sure if it's related.

Answer (score 7):

Getting the same issue. Resolved it by installing core-js as a top level dependency and then adding it as an option to .babelrc

```
npm install --save core-js@3
```

Then updated my .babelrc file to include it as an option:

```
 {
  "presets": [
    [ "@babel/preset-env", {
      "useBuiltIns": "entry",
      "corejs": 3
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": false }],
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings"
  ]
}
```

I referenced the docs here to figure it out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins

Comment: They say "core-js@2". Is it safe to use "core-js@3"?

Comment: @Holtwick take a look here: https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md

Comment: there's always a possibility of issues with major releases, of course.  
Here's a blog post by one of babel's authors, written at the time of babel 7.4.0 release a few days ago, with some migration guides and info:
https://babeljs.io/blog/2019/03/19/7.4.0#migration-from-core-js-2

Comment: down vote for failing to specify where the .babelrc file might be located

Answer (score 0):

This has been reported to parcel.js: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2819

This is due to a soft change in the newly released @babel/core 7.4 and seems to require a parcel.js change.

The solution so far is to either:

- lock @babel/core to ~7.3: `"@babel/core": "~7.3"`
- not upgrade the dependencies at all if they are locked

Comment: As of today, it seems it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have `core-js` as a dependency necessarily. Just set `core-js` version in your babel config file (`babel.config.js`) `@babel/env` preset as follows:

```js
...
[
  '@babel/env',
  {
    targets: {
    ...
    corejs: 'core-js@2'
  }
]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading through related discussions on github and the solutions proposed here, the following seems to be the way to go for now:

1. Add core-js@2 to your dependencies
   `npm i core-js@2`
2. Ignore the warnings when building

When playing around with the babel config modifying targets I ran into errors either when building or when serving the project.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says "You may need to specify core-js@2 as a top level dependency in your application". https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins

This worked for me:

```sh
npm i core-js@2
```

Then in `babel.config.js`:

```js
{
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/env", // or others like "@vue/app"
      {
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "core-js@2",
        // ...
```

Comment: down vote for failure to specify where the babel config file might be located

Comment: added the file name